# Is there a better solution for this ternary condition?

Tags: python, if-statement, variable-assignment, ternary

Imagine the following ternary condition:

```
foreground = self.foreground if self.foreground else c4d.COLOR_TRANS
```

In this case, I need to call `self.foreground` twice just to check if it *is* `True` or not.
Is there a way where I only need to call it once ?

Comment: Unless this is taking a very long time, I would leave it as it is - it is far more readable than doing `foreground = self.foreground or c4d.COLOR_TRAN` and the way you have it now means it is completely obvious what is going on. The "shorter to type" method is pretty confusing to look at.

Additionally, if that line of yours *is* taking too long to evaluate, I suggest fixing `self.foreground` to take less time to call rather than changing this line.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An equivalent expression is

```
foreground = self.foreground or c4d.COLOR_TRANS
```

Comment: ...because Python's logical operators don't just return booleans; they give you the actual value which caused them to make up their mind. (So e.g. `a or b` evaluates to `a` (not `True`) if a is true and `b` otherwise)

Comment: If both are false, there is a problem. in the if-else clause no.

Comment: @BrainStorm, sorry, what's the problem? `0 or ''` => `''`.

Comment: @BrainStorm, `'' or None` => `None`.

Comment: @senderle, +1 to this nice comment, i didn't knew! :D

Answer (score 3):

You can use the boolean operators:

```
foreground = self.foreground or c4d.COLOR_TRANS
```